# MySQL query get 1 result from each category LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have 10 posts, each post has a category.

```
Post Table
    ID| POST   |
    1 | post 1 |
    2 | post 2 |
    3 | post 3 |
    4 | post 4 |
    5 | post 5 |
    6 | post 6 |
    7 | post 7 |
    8 | post 8 |
    9 | post 9 |
    10| post 10|

Category table

    ID|Pid| Category
    1 | 1 | dog
    2 | 2 | dog
    3 | 3 | cat
    4 | 4 | cat
    5 | 5 | dog
    6 | 6 | horse
    7 | 7 | dog
    8 | 8 | cat
    9 | 9 | squirrel
    10| 10| dog
```

I'm trying to only retrieve 1 result from each category.  The categories will be dynamic, so I can't do a Where clause.

```
Select * from posts parent
LEFT join categories child on child.parent_id=parent.id
```

How do I change the query to accomplish this?

I should get post 1, post 3, post 6 & post 9 as results.

Comment: Post sample input data and desired result

Comment: why you want "post 1, post 3, post 6 & post 9 "?

Answer (score 0):

You can find one Pid per category using aggregate function `min` and then join it with the posts table to get the desired result.

```
select *
from post p
left join (
    select category, min(pid) pid
    from category
    group by category
    ) c on p.id = c.pid;
```